# How would I do Subsequent sort on a child table in asp.net mvc2 using Entity Framework

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, sorting, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to do something like this:

```
 ViewData.Model = _db.Questions  
                     .Include("QType")  
                     .Include("QTags")  
                     .Include("SubQuestions.Options")  
                     .Where(q => q.Active == true)  
                     .Orderby(q => Questions.Order)  
                     .Orderby(sq => SubQuestions.Order)  
                     .ToList();
```

But ofcourse it is not working as I want to. The Ordering works on `Question.Order`, but I would also the `Questions.SubQuestions` list to be ordered according to `SubQuestions.Order`.

Any blatant mistakes anyone can help me resolve?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your code accurate?  It doesn't look like you're using either `q` or `sq` in your order by clauses.  I'm pretty sure your problem though is that your **second** order by should be replaced with the `ThenBy` operator.

Comment: Hi Kirk, I also tried this: .Thenby(q => q.SubQuestions.Orderby(sq => sq.SQOrder) ) , but this doesn't work either. Could you give any tips / pointers?

Comment: @Priyeshj, you are returning a sequence of questions.  Each question can have *many* sub questions, correct?  What does it mean to sort on a column on the sub question table when returning results on the question?  In other words, if each question can have multiple sub-questions, then it doesn't make sense to order by those subquestions when you are returning the top-level questions.  Perhaps you want the MAX Order value for the sub-question?  Can you perhaps show some sample data that describes the results you expect?

Comment: I guess you might be correct. I ended up creating a separate View Model for the relationships, and sorting then dynamically in the views instead of model/controller. So no more .Thenby(...). Bad implementation, but works. Thanks for the clues.